# Create sparse index on MongoDB using official C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The official C# driver offers the ability to specify which fields to sort asc, desc, and geo. It doesn't offer sparse.

How do I do this directly from C#?

Comment: Do you mean sparse instead of partial? Partial indexes are not (yet) implemented.

Comment: Thanks @Remon - I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.1. driver has `SetSparse` in the IndexBuilder.

Comment: Thanks. Can it do compound indexes?

Comment: Yes, IndexKeysDocument. Read the API sir ;)